# Changing the proportions of a circle cut in half after cutting?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

If you make type on a path in Illustrator on a circle, and you cut the circle in half 50:50 to get the type the right way up in each half - can you then adjust the half to make it eg 60:40 or some other proportion (to allow for changing text length in the top half)???
Or do you have to cut the circle in the exact place you need to each time??

Comment: Why are you cutting the circle?

Comment: In order to get the text running in two different directions - clockwise for the top half and anti-clockwise in the bottom half?

Comment: Can you show us?  I'm having a hard time understanding what you're doing and why you're splitting as well.

Comment: It's very similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjUuJxgmVgE

Comment: I want to adjust the lengths of text above and below to take a greater or lesser proportion of the circle without producing a new artwork each time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cutting one circle, just create two circles on top of each other and use one to place text across the top and the other circle to place the text across the bottom.

You can then adjust how far you want the text to wrap around

Comment: Ah good thinking batman - now I need to go find a tutorial on layers!! :-)

Comment: You should be understanding layers as a basic before text on path :) but good luck!

Comment: I know, I shouldn't be running before I can walk - but there you go, needs must!! Thanks